# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException Error when trying to inject into running VM

Tags: java, jvm

I am trying to inject a .jar file in a running VM.

I've added tools.jar in the build path in eclipse, but when I try to run the injector, this error pops up. How should I add tools.jar to the project?

Full error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/tools/attach/VirtualMachine
        at src.testinjector.MainClass.main(MainClass.java:13)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.tools.attach.VirtualMachine
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 1 more
```

Comment: Show us the stacktrace including the **full** error message

Comment: And also the full command line used to run injector.

Answer (score 0):

you may try:

Give the path to tools.jar instead of being dependent on JAVA_HOME.

Note: JAVA_HOME/path to jdk/bin/ should not have any space.

Answer (score 0):

By default, the "tools.jar" classes are not loaded, your options are to either use a jdk that does load it, include tools.jar in your jar, or forcefully load it with the method below, *(note: this might not work on certain jdk/jvm's)*

```
private static void prepareAttach() throws NoSuchMethodException, MalformedURLException, InvocationTargetException, IllegalAccessException {
        String binPath = System.getProperty("sun.boot.library.path");
        // remove jre/bin, replace with lib
        String libPath = binPath.substring(0, binPath.length() - 7) + "lib";
        URLClassLoader loader = (URLClassLoader) [This Class].class.getClassLoader();
        Method addURLMethod = URLClassLoader.class.getDeclaredMethod("addURL", URL.class);
        addURLMethod.setAccessible(true);
        File toolsJar = new File(libPath + "/tools.jar");
        if (!toolsJar.exists()) throw new RuntimeException(toolsJar.getAbsolutePath() + " does not exist");
        addURLMethod.invoke(loader, new File(libPath + "/tools.jar").toURI().toURL());
    }
```

Comment: uses reflection because you cannot invoke loader.addURL() directly, sadly.